# How coordinate system shifting is related to similarity transformations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

I know that coordinate system shifting can be represented using matrices. But how exactly are similarity transformations related to coordinate shifts ?

Comment: Well, matrices transform under a basis change by a similarity transformation with the base change matrix (or, equivalently, transform in the adjoint representation of the symmetry group). Is there something specific you want to know about that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Can you tell me why the normal matrices preserve the angles where as others don't

Comment: Normal matrices are diagonalizable by a similarity transformation with a unitary matrix (which are just changes of orthonormal bases), thus, they just represent scaling of certain basis vectors. Since this unitary similarity to diagonal matrices is one definition of normal matrices, others have no chance to preserve angles the same way.